# How to convert x-www-form-urlencoded string to json in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
String source= "BRN=920736&STC=000&RMK=success&TRN=935851295243587"
```

How to convert the `x-www-form-urlencoded` string to json in dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Uri.splitQueryString`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/splitQueryString.html) to parse a `x-www-form-urlencoded` query string to a `Map<String, String>`.  Note that both keys and values will be `String`s, so if you want to interpret some values as, say, `int`s, you will need to explicitly parse them (e.g. with `int.parse`).

Example:

```dart
var source = "BRN=920736&STC=000&RMK=success&TRN=935851295243587";
var map = Uri.splitQueryString(source);
print(map); // Prints: {BRN: 920736, STC: 000, RMK: success, TRN: 935851295243587}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Uri.splitQueryString` works if you don't have repeated field names in the `x-www-form-urlencoded` form data. However, if you *do* have repeated fields such as:

```
a=1234&a=5678&b=9876
```

you'll need to use `Uri(query: source).queryParametersAll`. For example:

```dart
final source = 'a=1234&a=5678&b=9876';
final fields = Uri(query: source).queryParametersAll;
List<String>? a = fields['a']; // [ '1234', '5678' ]
String? b = fields['b']?.first; // '9876'
```